# How to use data returned by an asynchronous function in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to define a function that gets me a list of certain IDs from a response of a GET request:

```
var getList = function (){

    var list = [];

    https.get(options).on('response', function (response) {
        var body = '';
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            var obj = JSON.parse(body);
            for (i=0 ; i<obj.length ; i++){
                list.push(obj[i].id);
            }
            //console.log(list);
            //return list;
        });
    });
};
```

Now, I'd like to use that list from this function in other functions or simply assign it to a variable. I understand that since the function is asynchronous (well, the `https.get` one), returning the list won't mean much as the other code will not wait for this function to finish. Do I have to put all the remaining code inside the `response.end` call? I know I'm missing something very obvious here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accept a callback as a parameter and call it with the relevant data inside the response.end handler:

```
var getList = function (successCallback){

    var list = [];

    https.get(options).on('response', function (response) {
        var body = '';
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            var obj = JSON.parse(body);
            for (i=0 ; i<obj.length ; i++){
                list.push(obj[i].id);
            }

            // invoke the callback and pass the data
            successCallback(list);
        });
    });
};
```

Then you can call the `getList` function and pass in a callback:

```
getList(function(data) {
    // do some stuff with 'data'
});
```

Of course other options are to use some library implementing the [Promises](http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/) pattern to avoid callback hell.

Comment: Ah! That's it! Of course the callback passes the value. Thanks, that helped tremendously.

Answer (score -1):

make the list as global or accessible

```
var list = []

//declare a get method

function getUpdatedList(){
  return list;
}
```

if you call before ajax finish you will get null anfter you will get the actual data array, but in normal cases just uses callback functions like

```
function getList(callback){

    ///
    //
    response.on('end', function () {
        var obj = JSON.parse(body);
        for (i=0 ; i<obj.length ; i++){
            list.push(obj[i].id);
        }
        callback(list);
    });
}
```